# Check if app can start foreground service in background on Android 12+

Tags: android, foreground-service, android-12

Is there any method to check if my app can start foreground service in background on Android 12 before app actually try to do it and getting `ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException`?

Some method which checks that at least one of the conditions is fulfilled https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#background-start-restriction-exemptions

I start my background service as foreground in activity

```
try {
    context.bindService( // p.s. this context of application, it's bounded to app process instead of activity context
        getServiceIntent(context),
        object : ServiceConnection {
            override fun onServiceConnected(
                className: ComponentName,
                service: IBinder
            ) {
                // service is running in background
                startForegroundService(context)
                // service should be in foreground mode (at least it should be very soon)
                (service as LocalBinder).getService().initialize()
                context.unbindService(this)
                bindServiceInProgress.set(false)
            }

            override fun onServiceDisconnected(arg0: ComponentName) {
                bindServiceInProgress.set(false)
            }
        },
        AppCompatActivity.BIND_AUTO_CREATE
    )
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    bindServiceInProgress.set(false)
}
```

but `onServiceConnected` can fire too late when activity is not visible anymore but I still want to try start the service in foreground mode if it's allowed for this app, so I need some method to check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess we can try catch `ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException`

```
private fun makeServiceForeground(context: Context): Boolean {
    val intent = getServiceIntent(context)
    return try {
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, intent)
        true
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S && e is ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException) {
            // TODO: notification to disable battery optimization
        }
        false
    }
}
```